# TransactionScope, Transaction Escalation for the same connection string

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, transactionscope

After TransactionScope instantiation, I created EF context and saved some data, then I created another EF context and saved data again.  In the second EF, I got error "MSDTC on [SERVER] is unavailable".

The problem is solved by using one EF context for everything inside the transaction.  I thought that if I used the same connection string, there is no need for transaction escalation.

Anyone has explanation for this, what is your doubts?

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent transaction escalation, more than just using the same **connection string**, you've got to use the same **sql connetcion**.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229978%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), an escalation that results in the **System.Transactions** infrastructure transferring the ownership of the transaction to MSDTC happens when:

> At least two durable resources that support single-phase notifications are enlisted in the transaction. For example, enlisting a single connection with does not cause a transaction to be promoted. However, whenever you open a second connection to a database causing the database to enlist, the System.Transactions infrastructure detects that it is the second durable resource in the transaction, and escalates it to an MSDTC transaction.

This is most likely what's going on in your case.